# Approved method to navigate between pages on same website

Tags: php, javascript, html, onclick

I have researched many places to find an answer to this question, but they never quite answer my real question:  What is the best/approved way to move to a new page within the same website?  I have read that it is bad to use window.location because search engines will think you are hiding something. But, when I don't want to open a new window (window.open), then I don't know how else to do it. I use href anchors in links and form actions, where appropriate.  But when I have menus or buttons with onclick, then I need something else.

Here's an snippet of my code:

**my javascript:** (with one option commented)

```
function gotoCat() {
   var catcdF = document.catSelect.catcd.value; 
   <?php 
   echo "window.location.href='http://www.mysite.org".$pgmdir."services/busMenu.php?catF='+catcdF; ";
   /*
   echo "window.open('http://www.mysite.org".$pgmdir."services/busMenu.php?catF='+catcdF,'','resizable=1,scrollbars=1,toolbar=1,top=50,left=300,width=950,height=800,location=0'); ";
   */
   ?>
}
```

**My dynamic SELECT list in a form (within PHP):**

```
   echo " <select name='catcd' id='catcd' size='8' onclick=gotoCat() > \n"; 
             // display list of categories   
     if ($numcats == 0) { // print message text only
        echo "<option value='0' >".$catMsg."</option> \n";
     }
     else {
        for ($i=1; $i<=$numcats; $i++) {
         $catcd_db = $catAry[$i][1];
         $catName_db = $catAry[$i][2];
         echo "<option value='".$catcd_db."'> ".$catName_db." </option> \n";   
        }
     }
  echo "</select>";
```

So, as you can see, I just want a method to allow the user a choice and then automatically go to the correct web page once selected. This is not always in a select list. Often it's when they want to exit or get an error:

```
     if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
       echo "<br/> <p style='text-align:center;'> <button type='button' 
           class='buttonStyle' style='padding: 4px 20px;' value='Exit' ";
       echo "onClick=\"window.location.href='http://www.mysite.org/services/catSelbus.php?rc=1&func=Rev'\" > ";  
       echo "Exit </button></p> ";
    }
```

I cannot use "go back" because they need to go to a prior page, not the form they came from.

So, unless my navigation methods are really off-the-mark, I guess I need to know the acceptable method for using javascript onClick to move to the next page in the same website.  Is window.location okay, or should I use something else?

Any opinions or suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

To navigate to another page using Javascript, use:

```
window.location.href = "url";
```

That's how it's done and there's nothing wrong about it.

---

For the sake of argument, you *could* create a hidden link and simulate a click on it, but as I said, there's really no need.

Comment: So, you are saying that there is no issue doing window relocates within the same website? I have read so often that browsers may "blacklist" your site if you have redirects.  Isn't window.location a redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You can use php `header('location')` instead:

```
<form action="submit.php">

<input type="hidden" value="test" name="hidden1" />
<input type="submit" Value="Exit" ... />
```

**submit.php**

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST['hidden1'])
  {
    header('Location: http://www.mysite.org/services/catSelbus.php?rc=1&func=Rev');
    exit;
  }
?>
```

More info about `header('Location ...');`:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Instead of a hidden, you use your `select`'s value and get it via the `$_POST` variable.

Comment: Don't forget `exit();` after the `header()` call, otherwise PHP will merrily carry on running until aborted by the broken browser connection. It's a race condition and a source of many an awkward bug to find.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I cannot use PHP header though, because I write to the page with html prior to some re-locations.  I was wondering about something in your example however: how does php know about the POST value when it is not available until the form is processed?  PHP would be done by the time the POST was set. Maybe I am misreading this.